# Why is report generator raising exception when upgrading to tomcat 8.0.43

Tags: tomcat, jasper-reports

We found that JasperReports will raise the following error when upgrade tomcat from 8.0.30 to 8.0.43.

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFilePathname);
---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. java.lang.Double cannot be resolved to a type
            value = ((java.lang.Double)field_amount.getValue()); //$JR_EXPR_ID=15$
                      <-------------->
```

This error gone after downgrade tomcat to 8.0.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to JasperReports 6.3.1, older versions had a bug related to report compilation with ECJ 4.6.0 or newer.

Tomcat 8.0.43 comes with ECJ 4.6.1, while Tomcat 8.0.30 had ECJ 4.4.2.

Alternatively (if you'd prefer not to upgrade JasperReports), include [ecj-4.3.1.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.3.1/) in your webapp under WEB-INF/lib.